# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, zend

Me he hecho un elemento nuevo de formulario, un `zend_form_element` que hereda del campo texto de `zf1`.

El caso es que al usarlo en un formulario me lanza este warning:

> PHP Warning:  htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /srv/www/code/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php on line 905

y al hacer submit me lanza una respuesta http 502. Parece que cuando el form no es válido e itenta repintar los campos ocurre algún error.

Se os ocurre lo que podría pasar para que lanzase este mensaje?

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $this->setDecorators(array(
        'PrepareElements',
        array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'user/new-provider.phtml')),
    ));

    $this->removeElement('user_id');
    $this->userElement = new Admin_Form_Element_NewOrExistingUser(array(
        'name' => 'user_email',
        'label' => 'Email',
        'required' => true,
        'description' => 'Introduce el email del usuario existente, o crea uno nuevo',
    ));
}

class Admin_Form_Element_NewOrExistingUser extends Zend_Form_Element_Text
{
    public function init() 
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->setOptions(array(

            'label' => $this->getLabel(),
            'description' =>  $this->description,
            'autofocus' => 'true',
            'size' => 40,
            'maxlength' => 200,
            'decorators' => array(
                'ViewHelper',
                'Errors',
                array('Description', array('escape' => false, 'tag' => 'p',    'class' => 'description', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
                array('HtmlTag',     array('tag' => 'dd')),
                array('Label',       array('tag' => 'dt')),
            ),
            'value' => null,
            'disableTranslator' => true,
            'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
        ));            
    }

    public function isValidElement($value) 
    {   
        $valid = true;
        if ($this->required && $value == null) {
            $this->addError("El campo del usuario es obligatorio, introduce un usuario válido");
            $valid = false;
        }
        return $valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Incluye el código del formulario y a donde hace submit para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: creo que cuando no es valido y en el controlador seteo el campo de email no se hace bien.

Comment: Es imposible decirte qué está fallando si no incluyes el código que lanza el error. Es decir, sí te podemos decir que `htmlspecialchars` está recibiendo un parámetro del tipo incorrecto, pero si no compartes el código que incluye ese `htmlspecialchars` es imposible saber qué variable/parámetro le estás pasando y de qué tipo es.

Comment: gracias por las respuestas, el fallo venia del controlador. no estaba seteando bien le campo y de ahí el error. thanks a todos

Comment: Genial. Comparte el código relevante y cómo lo solucionaste y ponlo como respuesta. Podría servir de ayuda a alguien en el futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El fallo venía del controlador. No estaba seteando bien el campo y de ahí el error. Éste es el código:

```
public function validateUser($form){
  if(!$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
    $user = $form->getUser();
    //$form->getElement('user_mail')->setValue($user); // esto esta mal porque es un objeto
    //$form->getElement('user_mail')->setValue($user->getName());
  }
}
```